# Crear formulario de Pdf en Java

Tags: java, pdf, formularios, itext

Necesito crear varios formularios en java, cuando seleccione una persona que exporte sus datos a un PDF con un formulario ya diseñado. Conozco la librería 'itext' y 'lowagie' ya he creado algun PDF para sacar listado, el problema es que ahora tengo que hacer 8 formularios completamente diferentes y el tiempo que me puede llevar haciéndolo es tremendo. Quería saber si conoceis algún otro método o alguna página que te haga el diseño  mas rapidamente y despues puedas exportar el código a tu programa. Si hay otras opciones mejor.

Comment: Como dato adicional y al margen, ¿sabes que la librería iText es de pago si la usas comercialmente y no has publicado tu código?

Comment: Yo utilizo iReports, que te viene con las librerías de jasreports para crear formularios, pero no se si te servirá esta librería. Las que nombras en la pregunta no las he utilizado, tampoco las he visto nunca. Intenta descargarte el plugin iReports para netbeans. Yo he utilizado el iReports pero no el plugin si no las librerías y el programa.

Comment: Lo estoy usando de manera particular, ya lo había leido, pero muchas gracias por la información

Answer (score 0):

A mi me gusta [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/). Con esta herramienta puedes crear templates rápidamente y con posibilidad de usar base de datos, javascript, etc. Tienes que invertir algo de tiempo al principio. Birt usa Eclipse e I-Text por debajo y es [Open Source](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/about/).

Por cierto también puedes crearte unas funciones con posiciones absolutas con Itext para ir dibujando PDFs. Sólo tendrías que volver a llamar a esas funciones cuando quieras reutilizar el código para otros formularios.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación, trendré en cuenta la idea de las funciones pero es que cada formulario que tengo hacer es muy diferente y no podré reutilizarlo.